# how to check .Net framework 4.5 installed or not using java script

Tags: javascript

I am opening Workflow application on some button click action. So 
I would like to check whether or not the .Net framework 4.5 is installed using JavaScript before opening Workflow application as the application requires .NET framework 4.5.

How can I achieve this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes specified in the string of the User Agent, so could be extracted from there.

```
document.write(navigator.userAgent);
```

But I wouldn't say that this is reliable. For example, testing on numerous browsers shows this is only reported by IE on my machine:

> <sub>**Chrome**:*Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4*</sub>
>
> <sub>**FireFox**: *Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/15.0.1*</sub>
>
> <sub>**Internet Explorer**: *Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; **.NET CLR 2.0.50727**; **.NET CLR 3.5.30729**;
>   **.NET CLR 3.0.30729**; Media Center PC 6.0; **.NET4.0C**; **.NET4.0E**)*</sub>